# TokuMX and result size limit

Tags: aggregation-framework, tokumx

I know that the Tokutek guys are inspired just by the useful and demanded features from MongoDB. One of these very useful features in MongoDB 2.6 is: "The aggregation pipeline adds the ability to return result sets of any size, either by returning a cursor or writing the output to a collection."

The current TokuMX version 1.5 is based on MongoDB 2.4 but does anyone know if the hard size limit will be removed in the upcoming version? Any ETA?

Comment: This is a question only TokuMX devs can answer, I would recommend asking them instead of us

Comment: I hope that they're reading SO as well :)

Comment: Or, as I was trying to hint at, you could just post a issue: https://github.com/Tokutek/mongo

Comment: Or here as well: https://tokutek.atlassian.net/browse/MX/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel , at the end of the day you are posting to the mongodb tag a question which is only known to employees of a single company

Answer (score 1):

The specific ticket to add MongoDB 2.6 support is at https://tokutek.atlassian.net/browse/MX-1142

And I agree, this is probably not a question for stackoverflow.